# Object '.' not found while piping with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble, survival

I am trying to conduct a survival curve using the `survival` package. The MWE code is as follows:

```
df %>% 
  filter(fac <= "Limit") %>% 
  survfit(Surv(tte, !is.na(event)) ~ fac, data = .) %>% 
  ggsurvplot(fit = .)
```

I get the error `Error in eval(fit$call$data) : object '.' not found`

When I try to break this down further by:

```
 survfit <- df %>% 
  filter(fac <= "Limit") %>% 
  survfit(Surv(tte, !is.na(event)) ~ fac, data = .)

 ggsurvplot(fit = survfit)
```

I get an identical error. Is anyone able to figure out how to pipe from my dataframe all the way through a survival curve? The reason I would like to do this is to streamline the filtering of my dataframe in order to produce a multitude of different survival curves without having to create many subsetted dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, `ggsurvplot` expects an object of class `"survfit"` as its first argument but also needs the data set as an argument.

The example below is based on the first example of function
 `survfit.formula {survival}`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(survival)
library(survminer)

aml %>%
  survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = .) %>%
  ggsurvplot(data = aml)
```

[image]

In the question's case this would become

```
df %>% 
  filter(fac <= "Limit") %>% 
  survfit(Surv(tte, !is.na(event)) ~ fac, data = .) %>% 
  ggsurvplot(data = filter(df, fac <= "Limit"))
```